# Add / to python string

Tags: python, string, escaping

i want to create the following string: `Plots\0_test.png`

The *0* is in variable *i*. I code this:

```py
path = 'Plots' + '\\'  + str(i) + '_test.png'
```

and I get the following string: `Plots\\0_test.png`

I don't know, what is the fault. I hope you can help me.

Comment: If you want to be sure it is a valid path, you can use `os` module : `os.path.join('Plots',str(i)+'_test.png')`

Comment: @TitouanL i'm not sure OP is looking to build a string for a path, otherwise he'd be using the classic slash '/'.

Comment: @HCKRMVT The variable is called `path`. And in order to access a png file it makes sense. But you might be right.

Comment: Indeed, I made total abstraction of the variable name and file termination... But therefore shouldn't it be the opposite slash ?

Comment: I dont think it matters, you can hardcode a path with `/` characters, but `os.walk()` or `os.path.dirname()` return values with \ (printed as \\ as the question states)

Comment: In WIndows, backslash is the standard file separator, but forward slash also works (in Python). In other OSs, forward slash is the file separator.